# Creating a local users with different layers of authorization in Chef v 11

Tags: authentication, chef-infra

I wanted to try out creating a local users with different layers of authorization in open source version of Chef. Since AD integration is not possible in this version so is there a way apart from moving onto the enterprise edition to solve this problem.

I want to have roles and groups and assign various users to groups and with different roles.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thre's no way in Open Source Chef server 11, there's no ACL system. The best you can do is managing rights inside nginx toward API calls. Or just migrate to chef 12 which integrate this natively. (The latest sounds the best idea)